# Android retofit+rxjava how to process dynamic request parameter with repeatwhen

Tags: android, rx-java

I use retrofit+rxjava to process basic http get request. And the request will be repeated every 5 seconds. repeatwhen is exactly meet the requirement and which works well under the condition when request parameter never changed.

In my test case , the parameter will vary on every time of request , and the code below doesn't work .

```
netInterface
            .postRequest(requestData)
            .repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Void> observable) {

                    requestData.setFreeMemory(x);
                    return observable.just(reqeustData).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(this.requestSubscriber);
```

Comment: just a question you mentioned that you want GET request and you are using #postRequest method with interface.

Comment: did you get a solution Bill?

Answer (score 0):

You've used something that seems like it would be the best solution, but it seems non idiomatic to continue with this pattern. Check this out and let me know what you think! Psuedo code coming first and then I'll write real Java. Just want to get the idea down while it's fresh!

```
Observable.combineLatest(getTextToGetObservable, Observable.interval(5, SECONDS)
            .subscribe(netInterface::postRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this.requestSubscriber);
```

Also please note that you might need to look into you subscribeOn / observeOn logic. It may not be causing you any issues right now, but down the line it may and certainly does not appear idiomatic.

So, while my answer doesn't exactly answer your question about how to use repeatWhen to solve this issue, I hope this answer helps you solve your issue of making requests (either GET or POST - as another commenter pointed out, your question used both. No worries! That's easy to do. I just want to make sure that everyone reading my answer isn't as confused as I was at first. I'm gonna test this code with a quick app and see if it works. I'll format the code correctly if it does.

[Here is a link to the Android project that should provide you with the mechanisms needed to get going.](https://github.com/lustigdev/StackOverflowProblems/blob/stackoverflow/dynamic-network-request/app/src/main/java/com/example/michaellustig/dynamicnetworkrequests/MainActivity.java) There are a couple of small issues with the code as is, as it is not a perfect example demonstrating emission every 5 seconds, but that is an issue of desiring to reduce complexity of the example rather than be lazy. I am also really tired, but that's not the excuse I'm gonna use here. I'm also about to upload this video so you can see the whole process I went through in solving the problem. Would love to know if there's a better way. It certainly would not surprise me in the least based on my past experiences of the wonders of RxJava and Reactive Programming.

I'll also be uploading that recording of the process I went through in solving this issue and linking that when the video is ready.

[Here's the video! Looking forward to knowing your thoughts and hearing your feedback.](https://youtu.be/c0mRquCjENw)

I'll be adding notes to this answer as time goes by and I think about more things that are wrong with it, but for one, there is no handling for the unsubscription of this process. This will continue indefinitely until the process in which it is contained is cleaned up. I'll add proper handling of that later to the full example.